# How to perform undo Operation in textEditors like Contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Trying to perform the undo operation in the Contenteditable div(text editor) using JavaScript.
Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the browser's native undo/redo feature or if you want to get creative like providing a button for undo/redo, have a look at the commands you can use with [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)